# Paypal parallel payments implementation in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

I want to integrate [PayPal parallel payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPParallelPaymens) in Magento.

Is this possible through Magento's admin interface without working on the code? Are there any extensions available for this?

I have already found this [developer network post](https://www.x.com/blogs/easypaypalwithphp/2010/01/26/exploring-parallel-payments-with-php-with-a-sample-application) which is pretty helpful for implementing Parallel payments in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not currently implemented in Magento as far as I know.
You may want to follow this up on the Magento community boards.